# Python: Iterate through an html file

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, row

I'm trying to iterate through an html file from the internet.

```
target = br.response().read()
for row in target:
    if "[some text]" in row:
    print next(target)
```

The problem is this loop iterates over each character in the html file, so it'll never find a match. How do I get it to iterate through each row instead?

I've tried `target = target.splitlines()` , but that really messes up the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically want to achieve is the following (reading from a file, as your header suggests):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

with open("test.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "got" in line:
            print "found: {0}".format(line)
```

You want to open your file `("test.txt")`.

You read each line (`for .. in`)

and look if the line contains a string, where `in` comes in nice:)

If you are interested in the line number:

```
    for index, line in enumerate(file):
```

But beware the index starts with 0, so the current line number is `index+1`

Analog, if you want to read from a String as a *file*, take a look at [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm submitting an html form using the mechanize module. After getting the response br.response().read() I want to iterate through the html file/object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the page source for the file you're viewing, because that's what you're getting back as a response. I have a feeling the response you're getting doesn't actually have new lines where you want it to. For pages like http://docs.python.org/ where the source is readable your splitline() method works great, but for sites where the source essentially has no line breaks, like Google's homepage, it's a lot closer to the problems you're experiencing.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, your best bet might be to use an html/xml parsing library like lxml. Otherwise using [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is probably a pretty safe approach. Both are a lot better than trying to guess where the line breaks should be.